# servicestack handler for request not found - wsdls

Tags: servicestack

While trying to generate the wsdl for my services I get the message:

Handler for Request not found:

Request.PathInfo: /metadata/soap12

I've already found the issue - just post this here if somebody else runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a minor issue, but maybe someone else is struggeling.

if I point to the URI http://localhost:49490/api/ the request is forwarded (302) and the generated wsdl links point to the correct URI 
http://localhost:49490/api/soap12

but if I point to the URI http://localhost:49490/api/metadata directly the generated wsdl links looks like this: http://localhost:49490/api/metadata/soap12

which cause the problem described above.

[image: difference]